# Show Google location marks from KML file

Tags: php, google-maps, joomla, kml

How can I show Google map place-marks from a KML file.

Comment: Rahul -- what have you already tried ... and where is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tech.reumer.net/ - you can use the plugin to link to .kml